# How to use objects with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am new to vue.js and I have some questions, looking at their docs

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

They define a vue instance by a string selector. Is there a way I can replace `#app` with a string of the whole template.

Secondly, if I have two vue instances `vue_container` and `vue_item`, is there a way I can set up the vue instances such that I can nest them, something like:

```
vue_container.append('list', vue_item);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the use case for your first question? Why would you want to use an element that does not exist?

Comment: I want to work with the template in memory first, then nest them like a tree, then insert them all into the DOM from the root vue instance.

Comment: You cannot nest Vue instances. You can nest Vue components.

Comment: Not sure I understand that use case tbh, like the comment above says, Vue is about components; you nest components, and the virtual dom takes care of the rest. `#app` is just your entry point.

Comment: I updated the question above a bit. So instead of #app, I want to pass a full string of the template. And whats the difference between instances and components? How do you nest components?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the Vue docs and some of the example apps.

Comment: Looking at this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Registration but it doesn't show an example for how to nest components.

Comment: See [*Local Registration*](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration). You can use the `components` property in Vue instances **and** components

Comment: You also appear to be misunderstanding the [`el` property](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el). This is the **existing** element in your plain-old HTML document that Vue binds the instance to, eg `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: @omega It's literally the next section. You should at least *skim* the entire docs before starting development.

Answer (score 1):

> They define a vue instance by a string selector. Is there a way I can replace #app with a string of the whole template.

You are looking for the `template` option: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template

> Secondly, if I have two vue instances vue_container and vue_item, is there a way I can set up the vue instances such that I can nest them [...]

No. Vue uses components for nesting, please see here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html